# Making a comment box on a ASP.NET Core MVC Blog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm working on a blog in ASP.NET Core.

I am having trouble creating a comment system that will upload the comments to the database.

this is my comment repository

```
public class CommentRepo
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

        public CommentRepo(ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
            this.context = _context;
        }

        public IQueryable<Comment> GetAll()
        {
            return context.Comments.OrderBy(x => x.DatePosted);
        }

        public CommentViewModel AddComment(Comment comment)
        {
            var _comment = new Comment()
            {
                CommentedOnBlogId = comment.CommentedOnBlogId,
                Content = comment.Content,
                CommentUser = comment.CommentUser,
                DatePosted = DateTime.Now
            };

            context.Comments.Add(_comment);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return context.Comments.Where(x => x.CommentId == _comment.CommentId)
                    .Select(x => new CommentViewModel
                    {
                        CommendId = x.CommentId,
                        CommentContent = x.Content,
                        BlogId = x.CommentedOnBlogId,
                        DatePosted = x.DatePosted,
                        CommentAuthor = x.CommentUser

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

My PostComment method in CommentController

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PostComment(Comment model)
        {
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult(new {  });
            var repo = new CommentRepo(db);
            try
            {
                var comment = new Comment();
                comment.Content = model.Content;
                comment.DatePosted = model.DatePosted;
                comment.UserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                comment.CommentedOnBlogId = model.CommentedOnBlogId;

                //new JsonResult to handle the success
                result = new JsonResult(new { Success = repo.AddComment(comment) });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                result = new JsonResult(new { Success = false, Message = ex.Message });
            }
            
            return result;
        }
```

My Blog Details View

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="left-column">
        <div class="card">
            <p>@Model.BlogContent</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h5>@Model.BlogUser.Handle, @Model.DatePosted</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        <div class="card">
            <p>@Model.BlogUser.FirstName @Model.BlogUser.LastName</p>
            <img src="@Model.BlogUser.DisplayPicture" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>@comment.CommentUser.Handle</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            @foreach(var i in Model.Comments)
            {
                <div class="card">
                    <p>@i.Content</p>
                    <p>@i.CommentUser.Handle</p>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="card" id="commentForm">
                @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_commentPartial");}
            </div>
        </div>
```

My commentPartial view

```
@model MClyne_Theatre_Web.Models.Comment
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="addcommentbox">
    <h2>Add Comment</h2>
    @Html.TextArea("Supplier", null, new { @class = "tl_text_box_comments form-control" })
    <input id="btnComment" type="button" value="Add" />
</div>
}
```

I'm using Ajax to execute my PostComment from Controller

```
$('#btnComment').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "@Url.Action("PostComment", "Comment")",
                data: $("#commentForm").serialize(),
                success: function (responce) {
                    if (responce.Success) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                }
            }).done(function (responce) {
                if (responce.Success) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error!", responce.Message, "Error")
                }
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("Error!", "Error Occured", "Error")
            });
        });
```

Currently, this will execute my PostComment method but won't collect any information such as the Comment Content.

Thank you and sorry in advance.

Comment: You don’t need the Repository anti-pattern. **Your DbContext /is/ the repository**.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an AJAX post rather than just submitting the form directly using the button?  The JavaScript you have posted seems to add nothing to the process.

Also what version of .netcore are you using?

Comment: `commentForm` is the id of div in your code. It is not the id of form. Also textarea in the form is for Supplier property not for the content property of comment. This won't give you any thing in the comment object in controller. You need to change to `@Html.TextArea("Content",`. using partial view with model type will make things easier.

Comment: Your partial view only have a textarea which id and name is "Supplier",but you want to get `comment.Content,comment.DatePosted,comment.CommentedOnBlogId` in PostComment method.So you want to pass the data of `@i`?